# Clases con metodos

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Estaba viendo smartpointers en c++ y me topé con esta clase, la verdad no entiendo lo que quiere decir la linea seleccionada, **¿Me podrían explicar que es?** y **¿Que temas debería repasar para entenderlo mejor?**

```
class Foo{
    int x;
    public:
        explicit Foo(int x) : x{x} {}//Esta linea
        int getX() {return x;}
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

### Constructor

```
explicit Foo(int x) : x{x} {}
         ~~~
```

`Foo` es el constructor de la clase homónima, esta clase se puede construir recibiendo un `int`, dado que la clase `Foo` no dispone de ningún otro constructor, dicha clase **sólo** podrá ser construida pasando un entero (`int`).

### Explícito.

```
explicit Foo(int x) : x{x} {}
~~~~~~~~
```

El constructor de `Foo` está marcado como explícito, esto significa que sólo se puede construir con `int` **explícitamente** y que no se tendrá en cuenta ninguna conversión implícita. ¿Qué es una conversión implícita?.

Una característica de los constructores de objetos que reciben un parámetro tipo `P` es que permite convertir un objeto `P` en el objeto. Tomando un objeto construible con un entero (`int`) como ejemplo:

```
struct Entero { Entero(int) {} };
```

Podemos construir el objeto `Entero` [de las siguientes maneras](https://tio.run/##lZA9DsIwDIXn5hRvazvwP1ZMiJ0rmDRCkagTpakEqnoYzsAROFhxy98GYrMtv@/ZT3s/0UfiQ9/XMTQ6YsvRBIf2WWSWY462Q1coJTUqspzlqlXJbIYd1VS5GgtoVzl4CrdLZaLoSyMjHpna3q48VcmTTNkiL0b15rFgB0LDSB8L6SDE8icRZxwdDg2FcrzBCGGfvm32WL9eWP7085a4dHCDz3tsTraORprP7Vqg9B3mJZKBtfojklKwK8k3CSY2gTEvVNf3dw):

```
// Pasamos 1 como parámetro de construcción.
Entero a(1);
// Construimos un 'Entero' con 2 como parámetro de construcción y lo guardamos en 'b'
Entero b = Entero(2);
// Construimos un 'Entero' copiando otro 'Entero' existente.
Entero c = a;
// Construimos un 'Entero' pasando 3 como parámetro de construcción.
Entero d = 3;
```

En el caso de la instancia `d`, hemos transformado implícitamente el número `3` en un objeto de tipo `Entero`, pero si marcamos el constructor como explícito:

```
struct Entero { explicit Entero(int) {} };
```

La instancia `d` ya no es construible dando el siguiente error:

> ```
> error: no existe una conversión viable desde 'int' a 'Entero'
>         Entero d = 3;
>                ^   ~
> nota: el constructor candidato (el constructor de copia implícito) no es viable: no se conoce ninguna conversión de 'int' a 'const Entero &' para el 1r argumento
> struct Entero { explicit Entero(int) {} };
> ```

### Lista de inicialización del constructor

```
explicit Foo(int x) : x{x} {}
                      ~~~~
```

Tras la definición del constructor y antes del cuerpo del mismo, se pueden inicializar los sub-objetos que componen el objeto:

```
/*      definición
            |
   /--------^--------\        */
   explicit Foo(int x) : x{x} {}
//                       \__/ ^^ <---- Cuerpo del constructor
//                         |
//             Lista de inicialización
```

En la lista de inicialización del constructor **sólo** pueden listarse los sub-objetos del objeto que se está construyendo, por eso aunque el parámetro de construcción se llame `x` y la variable miembro de `Foo` se llame igual, no hay ambigüedad entre una y otra:

```
class Foo{
    int x;
//      ^ <-------------------\____ Variable Foo::x
    public: //                |
//                            |
//                            |
//                            v
        explicit Foo(int x) : x{x} {}
//                       ^      ^
//                        \    /
//                         \  /
//                          \/
//                           \___ Parámetro 'x'
        int getX() {return x;}
};
```